# A linear programming problem

Tags: linear-programming

Please guide me on the following question.

> Consider the LP problem
>
> maximize $x_1+x_2$
>
> subject to
>
> $x_1-2x_2\le10$
>
> $x_2-2x_1\le10$
>
> $x_1,x_2\ge0$
>
> Which of the following is true?
>
> $1.$ The LP problem admits an optimal solution.
>
> $2.$ The LP problem is unbounded.
>
> $3.$ The LP problem admits no feasible solution.
>
> $4.$ The LP problem admits a unique feasible solution.

The first line passes through $(0,-5)$ and $(10,0)$. The second line passes through $(0,10)$ and $(-5,0)$. They both intersect at (-10,-10). Thereby, I am getting that it would be an unbounded problem and won't have any feasible solution.

That is, according to me, $2nd$ and $3rd$ options are correct. But answer should be only one option. Please help.

Comment: It may be good for you to plot the feasible region - i.e. shade it.  For e.g. check $(5, 5)$ - why would you think there is no feasible region?

Comment: got it. I earlier thought only vertices can give us a feasible solution. But ur comment makes me think that a region can be feasible solution. that makes sense. so answer is 2. thanks!

Comment: @Ramit: The intersection of the all areas left after the constraints give the feasible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $x_1 = x_2 \geq 0$ and check if this is a feasible solution.  If so, then what happens to the objective function as $x_1 = x_2$ becomes larger and larger?

Comment: okay, understood. There are many feasible solutions, but it is an unbounded problem.